# How to click on repeated button on a page?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table layout like this:

```
 <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> <button> Click me </button>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> 2 </td>
      <td> <button> Click me </button>
    </tr>
    ....
  </tbody>
```

I only know the value of the first td (1,2, etc). Is there anyway to click on the appropriate second td (the button) while only knowing the first td? For example, can I dynamically get 2 and know to click on the second "Click me" button instead of the first one?

Answer (score 1):

yes there is way:

Basically, the `buttons` you want to click are **siblings** to the `td` elements you already know of.

Please try using locating an element via xpath sibling to locate those buttons:

```
//td[contains(text(),'1')]/following-sibling::*  //this reads, first locate an element of td type whose text() attribute contains '1', then find its immediate sibling.

//td[contains(text(),'2')]/following-sibling::*  //this reads, first locate an element of td type whose text() attribute contains '2', then find its immediate sibling.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an XPath:

```
twoClickMeButton  = driver.find_element(:xpath,"//td[text()='2']/../td/button")
```